# Django User as ForeignKey Error

Tags: django, django-models

I just simply want to  have multiple ssh-session to be associated with each user

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User

 class Sshsession(models.Model):
  session_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  # Other session attributes
  usr=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I do migrate I get an error

```
 int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

I tried doing User.id but didnt help.

Full Trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line    
utility.execute()
   File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djang/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
     executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
     self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake,   fake_initial=fake_initial)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
     state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
    File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
   File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
field,
    File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 382, in add_field
     definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
    File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
    File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 912, in get_db_prep_save
     return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 968, in get_db_prep_value
     value = self.get_prep_value(value)
     File "/home/ubuntu/blahblah/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
     return int(value)
  TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

Comment: models.ForeignKey('User')

Comment: That's not the full error you get. Please show it.

Comment: @dnit13 But will it associate to Model User??

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with that. Please post the full error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done Please See.

Comment: The code you have posted should work. You should add the omitted fields to get more help.

Comment: Do you have a `default` parameter in your `ForeignKey` that you omitted to post?

Comment: show the migration file